# How can I group elements of an array made with bmatrix like in this image?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

How can I put this kind of grouping under elements of an array? 
[image]

Like the image I want to make groups of l elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that I totally agree with the very good user @Zarko, in the first version you use `bmatrix` in the other versions of the code there is absolutely no need to use `bmatrix`.

Here there is my MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand\lowerbrace[2]{\mathrlap{\smash{\underbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix} #2 \end{matrix}}}_{\mbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}}}}#2}

\begin{document}
\[ \bm{y}=\begin{bmatrix} \lowerbrace{l}{1, \ldots, 1}, &\mkern-13mu  \lowerbrace{l}{-1, \ldots, -1}\end{bmatrix}^{T}\]

\[\bm{y}=\bigl[\,\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{l}, \underbrace{-1, \ldots, -1}_{l}\,\bigr]^{T}\]
\[\bm{y}=\bigl[\,\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{l}, \underbrace{-1, \ldots, -1}_{l}\,\bigr]^{\!\top}\]
\[\bm{y}=\bigl[\,\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{l}, \underbrace{-1, \ldots, -1}_{l}\,\bigr]^{\!\intercal}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
You need to use `\underbrace`.

To get the result of the image:

```
$y = [\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{l}, \underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{l}]$
```

Comment: Please exend your answer with MWE, that we can see, how you employ `\underbrace `  ...

Comment: This is not an MWE ... Please extend it to complete small document beginning with  `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that people can test it as it is ;-)

Comment: and where is used `bmatrix` in your code fragment as you ask in question?